# Export HTML to PDF (C++, Windows)

Tags: c++, winapi, pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking for a redistributable component to convert HTML to PDF.

I would - at the moment - like to avoid using a "PDF printer", as this requires a printer installation and some user "playing around" in the printers panel might break that feature.

The HTML is available in a Browser control or as external file. The HTML is normally fairly simple, but customers can create their own templates, so a "good range" of HTML should be supported.

Should be accessible for an automated process from C++ - DLL / COM / external executable with command line support are all fine.

Commercial is fine, but in the thousands is not an option right now.

So, which components do you know or can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) can function as a virtual printer but it's also usable via COM. The default setup even includes COM examples.

You can check the COM samples in the SourceForge SVN repository right here: http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdfcreator/trunk/COM/

Comment: I wanted to avoid "PDF printers", but finally we ended up with nuging PDFCreator to do what we need.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft Word installed, I guess you could automate the whole process using the "save as pdf" plugin that can be downloaded from the Microsoft Office Site.

You would automate word then open the HTML document inside word, then output as PDF. Might be worth a shot, if you're developing in a Microsoft Environment.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to have a look at [**PDFReactor**](http://www.realobjects.com/PDFreactor.808.0.html)