# Converting HTML file to PDF using Win32/MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, pdf-generation

As part of my application, my client has requested that I include an automated e-mailing system. As part of this system, I generate HTML code and use automation to send it via. Outlook.

However, they also require a PDF copy of the HTML document to be sent as an attachment. My initial attempts involved using [libHaru](http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page), which proved difficult to use efficiently, as I was required to create the PDF document from scratch, which required computation of the position of each of the lines in a table, and positioning of all the text, etc.

> I was wondering if there would be a way to programmatically convert HTML code (or an HTML file if need be) into a PDF document either by using Win32/MFC itself or an external library.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I am looking for solutions which minimize external dependencies.

Comment: Maybe you can use online api? Then http://www.convertapi.com/web-pdf-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should evaluate this utility wkhtmltopdf:
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

You can call it from the command line without the need to run a setup.

I use it generating my output documents as html then cal a ShellExecute(...) to convert it to PDF. It's great!

Inside uses webkit + qt. So compability with modern HTML is OK.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice solution, this is a lightweight solution which I can remotely download and install on my clients machine via. my own application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/), which can be used as a COM object (that acts pretty much like a printer). I haven't used it to print HTML, so I'm not sure, but my guess is that you'll probably end up having to instantiate a web browser control to render the HTML, and then feed it from there to the PDF control.

Comment: As far as I know, this can't be embedded in the application, so it becomes an external dependency, so I'm looking for solutions which minimize external dependencies, I'll update the question to clarify. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Some possible answers are in this thread:

[C++ Library to Convert HTML to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427927/c-library-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

Not sure if they will satisfy your particular requirements, but these might at least get you started.

Edit:

Some other possible options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323354/export-html-to-pdf-c-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Not MFC but you can try QtWebKit. It can render and export HTML to PDF, PNG, JPEG